# Is there an option in Laravel eloquent that allows to work with Hypertables ( Postgres )

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, timescaledb

I'm working with Laravel 7 / Postgres / TimescaleDB. I have a table that is an hypertable, and I am having an hard time dealing with it with Eloquent.

Is there an option to create a table as a hypertable with Eloquent ?

Comment: What are you doing, what do you want to happen, what is happening instead?